# Errors occur while building Awesome Map Editor (AME)

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I'm new to C++ and Qt, and I have no experience with programming in C++. But I really need some help with finding out the problem with building Awesome Map Editor (a map editor for the 3rd Gen Pokémon games).

I follow all the instructions, as it mentions on here: https://github.com/Diegoisawesome/AwesomeMapEditor

But upon building YAML-CPP, it comes up with multiple warnings and with this error:

```
/home/administrator/Documents/AME/AwesomeMapEditor/include/QBoy/Core/RomInfo.hpp:32:
 error: QString: No such file or directory
      #include <QString>
               ^~~~~~~~~
```

Now I'm not sure why this is happening, and I would like to know how to fix this issue.

If I ignore the errors and build Qboy then AwesomeMapEditor, I get these errors upon building AwesomeMapEditor:

> :-1: error: cannot find -lQBoy
>
> :-1: error: cannot find -lyaml-cpp
>
> :-1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I followed all the steps that was explained on it's Github repository, but it lead to these errors, how can I fix them? How can I build it properly?

I also have the compiler output as well, but it's huge and since there's no way for me to post a .txt file attachment to this, this is all I can type out.

Edit: Here's the AwesomeMapEditor.pro file incase anyone needs to help me fix anything:

```
#
# AwesomeMapEditor: A map editor for GBA Pokémon games.
# Copyright (C) 2016 Diegoisawesome, Pokedude
# License: General Public License 3.0
#


#
# QMake Settings, 1
#
QT         += core gui widgets
TARGET      = AwesomeMapEditor
TEMPLATE    = app
CONFIG     += c++11
DEFINES    += AME_EDITOR

# do only use if getting those useless BUILT_IN warnings
CONFIG     += warn_off


#
# QMake Settings, 2
#
VERSION = 1.0
win:QMAKE_TARGET_COMPANY     = DoMoreAwesome
win:QMAKE_TARGET_PRODUCT     = AwesomeMapEditor
win:QMAKE_TARGET_DESCRIPTION = A map editor for GBA Pokémon games.
win:QMAKE_TARGET_COPYRIGHT   = (C) 2016 Diegoisawesome, Pokedude


#
# QMake Settings, 3
#
INCLUDEPATH += include
INCLUDEPATH += include/AME/Forms
INCLUDEPATH += include/AME/Widgets
#INCLUDEPATH += include/AME/Widgets/OpenGL
INCLUDEPATH += include/AME/Widgets/Rendering
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../QBoy/include
DEPENDPATH  += $$PWD/../QBoy/include
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../yaml-cpp/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../yaml-cpp/include
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
#win32: LIBS += -lopengl32
#unix:  LIBS += -lGL


#
# QMake Settings, 4
#
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    unix|win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../QBoy/bin/debug/ -lQBoy
} else {
    unix|win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../QBoy/bin/release/ -lQBoy
}

unix|win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../yaml-cpp/bin/ -lyaml-cpp


#
# Source Files
#
SOURCES += \
    src/main.cpp \
    src/Forms/MainWindow.cpp \
    src/System/WriteEntry.cpp \
    src/System/ErrorStack.cpp \
    src/Text/Tables.cpp \
    src/Text/String.cpp \
    src/Structures/WildPokemonTable.cpp \
    src/Structures/WildPokemonSubTable.cpp \
    src/Structures/WildPokemonArea.cpp \
    src/Entities/MapScriptTable.cpp \
    src/Entities/ConnectionTable.cpp \
    src/Entities/EventTable.cpp \
    src/Graphics/Tileset.cpp \
    src/Graphics/TilesetManager.cpp \
    src/Mapping/MapBorder.cpp \
    src/Mapping/MapHeader.cpp \
    src/Mapping/MapNameTable.cpp \
    src/Mapping/Map.cpp \
    src/Mapping/MapBank.cpp \
    src/Widgets/QHexLineEdit.cpp \
    src/Widgets/QHexSpinBox.cpp \
    src/Mapping/MapBankTable.cpp \
    src/System/Configuration.cpp \
    src/System/LoadedData.cpp \
    src/Widgets/Misc/Messages.cpp \
    #src/Widgets/OpenGL/AMEMapView.cpp \
    #src/Widgets/OpenGL/AMEBlockView.cpp \
    src/Widgets/AMEImageButton.cpp \
    src/Forms/ErrorWindow.cpp \
    #src/Widgets/OpenGL/AMEBorderView.cpp \
    src/Structures/PokemonTable.cpp \
    src/Graphics/OverworldTable.cpp \
    #src/Widgets/OpenGL/AMEEntityView.cpp \
    src/Graphics/PropertyTable.cpp \
    src/System/Settings.cpp \
    src/Entities/EntityRawData.cpp \
    src/Mapping/MapLayoutTable.cpp \
    src/Widgets/QFilterChildrenProxyModel.cpp \
    src/Structures/ItemTable.cpp \
    src/Forms/SettingsDialog.cpp \
    src/Forms/TilesetDialog.cpp \
    src/Algorithm/PaletteQuantizer.cpp \
    src/Widgets/Listeners/MovePermissionListener.cpp \
    src/Widgets/Chunks.cpp \
    src/Widgets/QHexEdit.cpp \
    src/Widgets/Commands.cpp \
    #src/Widgets/OpenGL/AMEOpenGLShared.cpp
    src/Widgets/Rendering/AMEBlockView.cpp \
    src/Widgets/Rendering/AMEBorderView.cpp \
    src/Widgets/Rendering/AMEEntityView.cpp \
    src/Widgets/Rendering/AMEMapView.cpp


#
# Header Files
#
HEADERS  += \
    include/AME/Forms/MainWindow.h \
    include/AME/Structures/WildPokemonTable.hpp \
    include/AME/System/ErrorStack.hpp \
    include/AME/System/WriteEntry.hpp \
    include/AME/System/IUndoable.hpp \
    include/AME/Text/String.hpp \
    include/AME/Text/Tables.hpp \
    include/AME/Structures/WildPokemonSubTable.hpp \
    include/AME/Structures/StructureErrors.hpp \
    include/AME/Structures/WildPokemonArea.hpp \
    include/AME/Structures/WildPokemonEncounter.hpp \
    include/AME/Entities/Warp.hpp \
    include/AME/Entities/Sign.hpp \
    include/AME/Entities/EntityTypes.hpp \
    include/AME/Entities/Trigger.hpp \
    include/AME/Entities/Npc.hpp \
    include/AME/Entities/Connection.hpp \
    include/AME/Entities/MapScript.hpp \
    include/AME/Entities/AutoScript.hpp \
    include/AME/Entities/Tables/EntityErrors.hpp \
    include/AME/Entities/Tables/MapScriptTable.hpp \
    include/AME/Entities/Tables/ConnectionTable.hpp \
    include/AME/Entities/Tables/EventTable.hpp \
    include/AME/Graphics/Tileset.hpp \
    include/AME/Graphics/Tile.hpp \
    include/AME/Graphics/Block.hpp \
    include/AME/Graphics/GraphicsErrors.hpp \
    include/AME/Mapping/MapBlock.hpp \
    include/AME/Mapping/MapHeader.hpp \
    include/AME/Graphics/TilesetManager.hpp \
    include/AME/Mapping/MapBorder.hpp \
    include/AME/Mapping/MappingErrors.hpp \
    include/AME/Mapping/Map.hpp \
    include/AME/Mapping/MapBank.hpp \
    include/AME/Widgets/QHexLineEdit.h \
    include/AME/Widgets/QHexSpinBox.h \
    include/AME/Mapping/MapBankTable.hpp \
    include/AME/Mapping/MapNameTable.hpp \
    include/AME/System/Configuration.hpp \
    include/AME/System/LoadedData.hpp \
    include/AME/Widgets/Misc/Messages.hpp \
    #include/AME/Widgets/OpenGL/AMEMapView.h \
    #include/AME/Widgets/OpenGL/AMEBlockView.h \
    include/AME/Widgets/AMEImageButton.h \
    include/AME/Forms/ErrorWindow.h \
    #include/AME/Widgets/OpenGL/AMEBorderView.h \
    include/AME/Structures/PokemonTable.hpp \
    include/AME/Graphics/OverworldTable.hpp \
    #include/AME/Widgets/OpenGL/AMEEntityView.h \
    include/AME/Graphics/PropertyTable.hpp \
    include/AME/Graphics/Property.hpp \
    include/AME/System/Settings.hpp \
    include/AME/Mapping/MapName.hpp \
    include/AME/Mapping/MapLayoutTable.hpp \
    include/AME/Widgets/QFilterChildrenProxyModel.h \
    include/AME/Structures/ItemTable.hpp \
    include/AME/Forms/SettingsDialog.h \
    include/AME/Forms/TilesetDialog.h \
    include/AME/Algorithm/PaletteQuantizer.hpp \
    include/AME/Widgets/Chunks.h \
    include/AME/Widgets/Commands.h \
    include/AME/Widgets/QHexEdit.h \
    #include/AME/Widgets/OpenGL/AMEOpenGLShared.hpp
    include/AME/Widgets/Rendering/AMEBlockView.h \
    include/AME/Widgets/Rendering/AMEBorderView.h \
    include/AME/Widgets/Rendering/AMEEntityView.h \
    include/AME/Widgets/Rendering/AMEMapView.h \
    include/AME/Widgets/Listeners/MovePermissionListener.h


#
# Forms
#
FORMS    += resources/UI/MainWindow.ui \
    resources/UI/ErrorWindow.ui \
    resources/UI/SettingsDialog.ui \
    resources/UI/TilesetDialog.ui

#
# Resources
#
RESOURCES += \
    resources/images.qrc #\
    #resources/shaders.qrc

DISTFILES += \
    resources/config/BPRE.yaml \
    #resources/shaders/NormalFragmentShader \
    #resources/shaders/PrimitiveVertexShader.glsl \
    #resources/shaders/PrimitiveFragmentShader.glsl
```

Now how do I get these lines to work? Please help!

```
#
# QMake Settings, 4
#
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    unix|win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../QBoy/bin/debug/ -lQBoy
} else {
    unix|win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../QBoy/bin/release/ -lQBoy
}

unix|win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../yaml-cpp/bin/ -lyaml-cpp
```

Edit 2: Okay! I've fixed the problem, thanks to a friend of mine! The QBoy and yaml-cpp folders needed to be in the same directory as AwesomeMapEditor, not in the AwesomeMapEditor folder itself, and they needed to be named as such.

The directory needs to be structured like this:

```
[root folder]
      |-------[AwesomeMapEditor]-----AwesomeMapEditor.pro
      |
      |-------[QBoy]-----------------QBoy.pro
      |
      --------[yaml-cpp]-------------CmakeLists.txt
```

Comment: Have you installed the prerequisite development packages for your system? Like the Qt and yaml-cpp development packages?

Comment: Where is the yaml-cpp development package? I can't find it anywhere online, just only the source code of yaml-cpp, which I'm using and opened in Qt with AwesomeMapEditor and Qboy

Comment: Then it seems that you need to build and install it on your own.

Comment: I've tried building them separately just now, I put the built files into the same location as the build location for AwesomeMapEditor, along with putting the include files in their respective location, and it came up with this error:
:-1: error: cannot find -lQBoy
:-1: error: cannot find -lyaml-cpp
:-1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I'm not sure what that means

Comment: I've updated the question, and I still have the same errors coming up, and I don't know how to fix this, please help!

Comment: Okay! I've fixed the problem, thanks to a friend of mine! The QBoy and yaml-cpp folders needed to be in the same directory as AwesomeMapEditor, not in the AwesomeMapEditor folder itself, and they needed to be named as such.

Comment: Perhaps you should write that as an actual answer? It helps future people with the same problem if you have an actual answer that is marked as accepted.

Comment: There we go! Updated it so it will help others with the same issue